# How do I create a custom RegistrationForm using django-registration in Django 5.0.2 with Django Registration 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I admit I'm new to Django but I've been banging my head against the wall with this problem all day. I've created a new application and inherited classes from django_registration, but it seems *my form data is never saved*. My fields show up and are accessible on the front end as well as the administration area, but *user registration never seems to happen and I don't get an error*. (It is working fine with standard django-registration but I want to expand it and plan for the future.)

forms.py

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from authentication.models import MyCustomUser
from django import forms

class MyCustomUserForm(RegistrationForm): 
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = MyCustomUser
        #fields = "__all__"
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_photo', 'password1', 'password2']
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('APPLICANT', 'Applicant'),
        ('EMPLOYEE', 'Employee'),
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        (None, 'None')
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField()
    #username = forms.CharField(max_length = 100) #this is already handled for us in AbstractUser
    #email  = forms.EmailField(max_length = 100) #this is already handled for us in AbstractUser
    #password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), max_length = 100) #this is already handled for us in AbstractUser
    #password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(),  max_length = 100) #this is already handled for us in AbstractUser
    first = forms.CharField(max_length = 100 )
    last = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    #USERNAME_FIELD = username #this is already handled for us in AbstractUser
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import MyCustomUserForm
from .models import MyCustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyCustomUserForm
    #form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = MyCustomUser
    list_display = ["email", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "profile_photo", "role"]

admin.site.register(MyCustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.MyCustomUser'
```

urls.py

```
path('accounts/register/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='django_registration_register')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views import generic
from django_registration.views import RegistrationView as BaseRegistrationView
from authentication.forms import MyCustomUserForm

class SignUpView(BaseRegistrationView):#generic.CreateView
    form_class = MyCustomUserForm
    template_name = "authentication/registration_form.html"
```

I tried adding methods from https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/trunk/src/django_registration/backends/activation/views.py into my views.py but there is no difference. I thought if I inherited the class the methods would be accessible anyway. I've scoured the documentation at https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html trying to figure out what I need to do but it's not clear to me what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyCustomUser` model inherits from `AbstractUser`, which is correct but the usage of Django forms fields directly in your model (`first` and `last` variable) is not correct.
Models should define database fields, not form fields. You should remove those and use the `first_name` and `last_name` fields provided by AbstractUser like below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('APPLICANT', 'Applicant'),
        ('EMPLOYEE', 'Employee'),
        ('ADMIN', 'Admin'),
        (None, 'None')
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photos/', blank=True, null=True)  # Specify upload directory and make it optional if you want
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Ahh so the places I was looking using forms.xxx was completely wrong (probably an earlier version of Django) and I should be using only models.xxx?

Comment: @CoreyManshack Yes, you are right

Comment: Thanks so much Mohammad! I'm moving on to customizing the admin area based on this model now :) Your suggestions were spot on.